# Disable pinch zoom in webkit (or electron)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, electron

Is there any way to disable pinch zoom in an [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app?

I can't get it to work from inside the web-view with normal javascript methods as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23510108/665261

It seems the `--disable-pinch` flag is [not supported by electron](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md).

I have experimented with various methods using:

1. `event.preventDefault()` on javascript `touchmove/mousemove` events
2. `meta viewport` tags in HTML
3. `-webkit-text-size-adjust` in CSS
4. flags/config for electron

Is there any method either for webkit in general, or [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) in particular?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

Use [webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-frame.md#webframesetzoomlevellimitsminimumlevel-maximumlevel) (v0.31.1+) in **render process** ([Differences Between Main Process and Renderer Process](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md#differences-between-main-process-and-renderer-process)). Because smart zoom on mac still work with document.addEventListener.

Example `require('electron').webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1)`

---

**UPDATE:**

`deltaY` property for pinch zoom has `float` value, but normal scroll event return `int` value. Now solution has no problem with ctrl key.

**[Demo 2](http://output.jsbin.com/tehidu)**.

```
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if(e.deltaY % 1 !== 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

---

Using Chromium `monitorEvents(document)` I found that is responsible for this event `mousewheel`. I don't know, why `mousewheel` triggered with pinch zoom.
Next step, find difference between normal scroll and pinch zoom.

Pinch zoom has an attribute `e.ctrlKey = true`, and normal scroll event has `e.ctrlKey = false`. But if you hold down `ctrl` key and scroll a page, `e.ctrlKey` equal `true`.

I couldn't find a better solution. :(

**[Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/yosezo)**

```
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Combining this with a keydown/keyup event to check if ctrlKey is set by the actual key using a global flag could possibly solve the differentiation problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems very difficult for desktop browser to prevent pinch zoom.

Here are some ideas though!

1) By using some gestures javascript like [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/), detect Pinch event and try to prevent it using e.preventDefault

OR

2) Design everything using "%" in css, or use newer units like "vm" etc, (if possible). This way, even page will be zoomed, but content will stay the same for any zoom level.

All the best!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I tried both solutions. Hammer, awesome as it is, does not seem to help with this. It seems to add recognisers as a level on top of events, I think I need something that helps to access more low level functionality. The second one seemed to have no effect when I put font size as percent rule on body, html, paragraph etc...

Answer (score 2):

Answer from [GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8793):

"If you are looking for a way how to prevent zoom from **main** process, you can use:"

```
const webContents = mainWindow.webContents;
webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  webContents.setZoomFactor(1);
  webContents.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);
  webContents.setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(0, 0);
});
```

`mainWindow` is variable where you have `new BrowserWindow`, e.g.:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 440,
  height: 750,
  // ...
});

const webContents = mainWindow.webContents;
webContents.on("did-finish-load", () => {
  webContents.setZoomFactor(1);
  webContents.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);
  webContents.setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(0, 0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only working way in my desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you can't use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Put that in the header and it keeps devices from zooming.

Comment: Oh. That is my trick when I want to disable zooming on mobile. Never had to worry about disabling zooming when I'm on a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I searched so long and hard for a simple solution to this problem with no avail...but later I discovered a plugin called fullpage.js that was able to prevent pinch zoom while still allowing touch gestures.  Through the process of js/css elimination, I discovered a very simple solution:

```
touch-action: none;
```

Adding this to my full page element successfully prevented pinch zoom but allowed me to scale fabricjs objects with pinching.  Hooray !

Comment: thnks for that, i was beleve in simple solution

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = require('electron')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-pinch');
```

Solution found by mixing these two links:

1 - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8793#issuecomment-289791853

2 - https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md

Answer (score 1):

I had to set `{ passive: false }` to make it work. Don't ask me why.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  if(e.ctrlKey) e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

meta tag should have worked. Try using the minimum-scale=1.0

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

And if it also not works then add both the minimum and maximum scale

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

P.S. : It will disable zooming on mobile phones only.

Comment: It probably works for mobile, I want a solution that also works for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I got the easiest fix for this, in the index.html or similar file for your project, within the script tag, include electron and configure zoom level as below,

```
<script>
const electron = require('electron'); // Include electron
electron.webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1); // Set min max zoom level as 1
const { ipcRenderer } = electron;
...
</script>
```

This works perfectly fine across devices.
The viewport meta tag approach doesn't work well on desktop, only fixes issue on mobile devices.