# Disable zooming (both pinch zoom and smart zoom [mac]) in electron

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, electron

Does anyone have a working solution to disable all kinds of zooming in electron v0.35.0? (including pinch zoom and smart zoom (on mac))

Comment: I'm pretty sure the viewport tag can handle that.

Comment: Tried it before and didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari  I do not know why that wouldn't work.

Comment: @durbnpoisn It's not a duplicate, that's for mobile view. I want to disable it in electron (desktop app). Somehow, the developers of atom managed to disable it in their app, so it must be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Add following to render process:

```
var electron = require('electron');
electron.webFrame.setZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);
```

See [Disable pinch zoom in webkit (or electron)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929411/disable-pinch-zoom-in-webkit-or-electron)