# Touchpad Pinch to zoom not working in Electron (MacOS)

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, pinchzoom

I am showing web content in a BrowserView in Electron, and looking to allow pinch to zoom.  I've tried the following that didn't work:

```
  view.webContents.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1, 3)
  view.webContents.setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(1, 3)
```

Manually setting the zoom factor does seem to work:

```
view.webContents.setZoomFactor(3)
```

But nothing that I've tried can enable the user to zoom.

One thing confusing me is that in trying to search for the answer, everybody seems to have the *opposite* problem:
[Disable zooming (both pinch zoom and smart zoom [mac]) in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962824/disable-zooming-both-pinch-zoom-and-smart-zoom-mac-in-electron)
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8793

So I'm wondering did something change?
I am on electron 4.0.6, Node v11.12.0.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found where they changed it: https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/12679

And others have this problem:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12631#issuecomment-447495983

Still trying to determine the exact fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the setVisualZoomLevelLimits method on the webFrame object instead of on the webcontent. As is described here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15417

In your renderer you should add:

```
webFrame.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1, 4);
```