# Is it possible to disable zoom in/out functionality in a Electron electron-quick-start JS app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

This question is specific to electron-quick-start, so it's not a duplicate.

I'm in the very first steps of JS desktop apps with https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start, I have the code and I can run the app on my mac(hine).

I've note It's possible to zoon in/out the text on the app, which is a feature common to web. Not so common to desktop apps.

How do I disable that behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable pinch zoom in webkit (or electron)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929411/disable-pinch-zoom-in-webkit-or-electron)

Comment: This question is specific to electron-quick-start.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929411/disable-pinch-zoom-in-webkit-or-electron

Comment: From there I understand how to prevent mouse-made zoom. I still can do Ctrl++/Ctrl+-. Perhaps you can point me to the specific part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to the JavaScript file that your rendered `html` file is sourcing in (see, [main process vs renderer process](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md#differences-between-main-process-and-renderer-process)).

```
var webFrame = require('electron').webFrame;
webFrame.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1, 1);
webFrame.setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(0, 0);
```

In your case, it's `renderer.js` for the electron-quick-start app.

Documentation:
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-frame.md#webframesetzoomlevellimitsminimumlevel-maximumlevel

Comment: This should prevent `Ctrl++`/`Ctrl+-` also?

Comment: @KcFnMi I'ed recommend you try it out and see if it works. The documentation I linked above offers other methods related to setting the zoom level.

Comment: @KcFnMi I added an edit that I believe is a minor improvement on your answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do the same, but in the Main Process (in your case in `main.js`), you can do this :

```
let webContents = mainWindow.webContents
webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
  webContents.setZoomFactor(1)
  webContents.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1, 1)
  webContents.setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(0, 0)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The `setVisualZoomLevelLimits` command is deprecated.

```
var app = require('electron')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-pinch');
```

Solution found by mixing these two links:

1 - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8793#issuecomment-289791853

2 - https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, as @5war00p has mentioned in an answer above, the only solution is to use `globalShortcut` similar to his proposed method. But his way is a little unpolished, and in fact can cause some problems. I suggest doing this in your `main.js` after creating your window object:

```
const { globalShortcut } = require('electron');

window.on('focus', () => {
  globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+0", () => { return });
  globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+plus", () => { return });
  globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+=", () => { return });
  globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+-", () => { return });
  globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+_", () => { return });
});

window.on('blur', () => {
  globalShortcut.unregister("CommandOrControl+0");
  globalShortcut.unregister("CommandOrControl+plus");
  globalShortcut.unregister("CommandOrControl+=");
  globalShortcut.unregister("CommandOrControl+-");
  globalShortcut.unregister("CommandOrControl+_");
});
```

This covers all the zoom related shortcuts, and doesn't interfere with other shortcuts that use control or command keys. You can also use ipc calls in the registered callbacks to use your own handlers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that adding the following to `renderer.js` does the job:

```
var webFrame = require('electron').webFrame;
    webFrame.setVisualZoomLevelLimits(1,1);
require('electron').webFrame.setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(0, 0);
```

Both, zoom via mouse and via Ctrl++/Ctrl+- are disabled.

If some one has comments or a better answer I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome removed setLayoutZoomLevelLimits(0,0) as it is beyond electron limits now,

- https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/breaking-changes#removed-webframesetlayoutzoomlevellimits
- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/938b37a6d2886bf8335fc7db792f1eb46c65b2ae/third_party/blink/common/page/page_zoom.cc#11

So, `Ctrl/Cmd +` and `Ctrl/Cmd -` will trigger zoom actions, there is a cool workaround that I recommend to register shortcut and stop the action by using below code snippets:

- onFocus return nothing

```js
window.on('focus', () => {
  globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl", () => { return })
})
```

- onBlur unregister the shortcut

```js
window.on('blur', () => {
  globalShortcut.unregister("CommandOrControl+=")
  globalShortcut.unregister("CommandOrControl+-")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

custom menu is the only right way to go
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu#examples

```js
const customMenuTemplate = [
  ...(process.platform === 'darwin'
    ? [
        {
          label: app.name,
          submenu: [
            { role: 'about' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'services' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'hide' },
            { role: 'hideothers' },
            { role: 'unhide' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            { role: 'quit' },
          ],
        },
      ]
    : []),
  {
    label: 'File',
    submenu: [process.platform === 'darwin' ? { role: 'close' } : { role: 'quit' }],
  },
  {
    label: 'Edit',
    submenu: [
      { role: 'undo' },
      { role: 'redo' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'cut' },
      { role: 'copy' },
      { role: 'paste' },
      ...(process.platform === 'darwin'
        ? [
            { role: 'pasteAndMatchStyle' },
            { role: 'delete' },
            { role: 'selectAll' },
            { type: 'separator' },
            {
              label: 'Speech',
              submenu: [{ role: 'startSpeaking' }, { role: 'stopSpeaking' }],
            },
          ]
        : [{ role: 'delete' }, { type: 'separator' }, { role: 'selectAll' }]),
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'View',
    submenu: [
      { role: 'reload' },
      { role: 'forceReload' },
      { role: 'toggleDevTools' },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'resetZoom', enabled: false },
      { role: 'zoomIn', enabled: false },
      { role: 'zoomOut', enabled: false },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { role: 'togglefullscreen' },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Window',
    role: 'window',
    submenu: [
      { role: 'minimize' },
      { role: 'zoom' },
      ...(process.platform === 'darwin'
        ? [{ type: 'separator' }, { role: 'front' }, { type: 'separator' }, { role: 'window' }]
        : [{ role: 'close' }]),
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Help',
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'Learn More',
        click: async () => {
          const { shell } = require('electron');
          await shell.openExternal('https://electronjs.org');
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

In the above code, we disable the zoom functionality by setting enabled: false on the resetZoom, zoomIn, and zoomOut roles.

Then add the custom menu to your app.

```js
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(customMenuTemplate);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Voila

Comment: This is a nice and neat solution, but its problem is that you cannot handle those shortcuts yourself after disabling them. The question only looks for disabling and so this seems enough, but in many real-life scenarios you will also need to handle them your own way.